# Globalize.format not formatting the date to "dd/MM/yyyy" format

Tags: javascript, javascript-globalize

I am using [Globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) to format a date. But it is not working properly with German culture (de-DE) and the date format "dd/MM/yyyy"

I have changed the system locale to German culture and also changed the browser culture to German.

I am using the following line to convert the date:

```
Globalize.format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "de-DE");
```

The expected output is `21/04/2015` but the actual output is `21.04.2015`

Why is the date being converted with the `.` symbole instead of the `/` symbol?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code?

Answer (score 2):

The library is treating `/` also as placeholders for the localization-specific separator. For `de-DE`, the common separator is `.` rather than `/`.

If you would like to keep the slashes anyways, you can quote them to disable the substitution:

```js
console.log(Globalize.format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "de-DE"));
console.log(Globalize.format(new Date(), "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", "de-DE"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/0.1.1/cultures/globalize.culture.de-DE.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `21.04.2015` is the traditional German date format. See [Date Format By Country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) and scroll down to `Germany`.

If you wanted to make it `21/04/2015`, you can try this:

`Globalize.format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy"); // without the culture`

Below is a runnable code snippet to see this in action:

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

date.innerHTML = Globalize.format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

```html
<div id="date">this becomes the date in the correct format</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
```